# Scaling an android View

Tags: android, android-layout

ok, I'm going to ask this because I really can not find an answer, after scouring for hours.

I'm making an android game, and I have a gameboard 'view'. My gameboard view has a few things - it has a background image, and then it has a grid of board pieces ontop of it.

I want the user to be able to double tap to zoom in, and then pan around the board.

I've been able to apply a transform in the past to get this effect (on other platforms) but I'm not sure how to do this in Android (I'm still new) - does anyone know how to apply transforms or achieve the above effect, WITHOUT me having to calculate the position of everything in my view?

Please dont suggest Canvas - I want my game pieces to be objects, and I want to be able to listen for 'on touch' events (AKA I do not want to have to figure out what the user touched when they touch the screen). I also want this for Android 2.1+

Thanks for any help ahead of time!!

Comment: Was going to suggest the canvas until you said not to. :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately doing this with views does require recalculating sizes and seems very tedious. I'm sure you know that Canvas has various matrix transformations one can apply.

If this functionality is important to you, I would think that figuring out how to have your Canvas objects receive touch events is the easier of the two paths, given that most games using the Canvas will also be receiving touch events and correlating them with the underlying game models.